# scipy `SparseEfficiencyWarning` when division on rows of csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Suppose I already had a `csr_matrix`:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
indptr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
indices = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
mat = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(3, 3))
print(mat.A)

[[1. 0. 2.]
 [0. 0. 3.]
 [4. 5. 6.]]
```

it's simple if I want to divide a single row of this csr_matrix:

```py
mat[0] /= 2
print(mat.A)

[[0.5 0.  1. ]
 [0.  0.  3. ]
 [4.  5.  6. ]]
```

However, if I want to change multiple rows, it throws an warning:

```py
mat[np.array([0,1])]/=np.array([[1],[2]])
print(mat.A)

[[1.  0.  2. ]
 [0.  0.  1.5]
 [4.  5.  6. ]]

SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray(i, j, x)
```

How come division on multiple rows change its sparsity? It suggests me to change to lil_matrix, but when I checked the code of `def tolil()`:

```py
def tolil(self, copy=False):
    lil = self._lil_container(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype)

    self.sum_duplicates()
    ptr,ind,dat = self.indptr,self.indices,self.data
    rows, data = lil.rows, lil.data

    for n in range(self.shape[0]):
        start = ptr[n]
        end = ptr[n+1]
        rows[n] = ind[start:end].tolist()
        data[n] = dat[start:end].tolist()

    return lil
```

which basically loops all rows, I don't think it's necessary in my case. What may be the correct way if I simply want to divide a few rows of a `csr_matrix`? Thanks!

Comment: The warning says that the action changes sparsity.  See my answer to see why.  The warning is not suggesting changing the matrix to `lil` for this particular task.  It's saying that if the matrix is already `lil`, the assignment may be more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix:

```
In [208]: indptr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
     ...: indices = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
     ...: data = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
     ...: mat = sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(3, 3))
In [209]: mat
Out[209]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [210]: mat.A
Out[210]: 
array([[1., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

Simple division just changes the `mat.data` values, in-place:

```
In [211]: mat/= 3
In [212]: mat
Out[212]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [213]: mat *= 3
In [214]: mat.A
Out[214]: 
array([[1., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

The RHS of your case produces a `np.matrix` object:

```
In [215]: mat[np.array([0,1])]/np.array([[1],[2]])
Out[215]: 
matrix([[1. , 0. , 2. ],
        [0. , 0. , 1.5]])
```

Assigning that to the `mat` subset produces the warning:

```
In [216]: mat[np.array([0,1])] = _
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:146: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray(i, j, x)
```

Your warning and mine occurs in the set step:

```
self._set_arrayXarray(i, j, x)
```

If I divide again I don't get the warning:

```
In [217]: mat[np.array([0,1])]/=np.array([[1],[2]])
In [218]: mat
Out[218]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Why?  Because after the first assignment, `mat` has 9 non-zero terms, not the original six.  So [217] doesn't change sparsity.

Convert `mat` back to 6 zeros, and we get the warning again:

```
In [219]: mat.eliminate_zeros()
In [220]: mat
Out[220]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [221]: mat[np.array([0,1])]/=np.array([[1],[2]])
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:146: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray(i, j, x)
```

and a change in sparsity:

```
In [222]: mat
Out[222]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Assigning a sparse matrix of [215] doesn't trigger the warning:

```
In [223]: mat.eliminate_zeros()
In [224]: m1=sparse.csr_matrix(mat[np.array([0,1])]/np.array([[1],[2]]))
In [225]: m1
Out[225]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [226]: mat[np.array([0,1])]=m1
In [227]: mat
Out[227]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

===

The [215] division is best seen as a `ndarray` action, not a sparse one:

```
In [232]: mat[np.array([0,1])]/np.array([[1],[2]])
Out[232]: 
matrix([[1.     , 0.     , 2.     ],
        [0.     , 0.     , 0.09375]])
In [233]: mat[np.array([0,1])].todense()/np.array([[1],[2]])
Out[233]: 
matrix([[1.     , 0.     , 2.     ],
        [0.     , 0.     , 0.09375]])
```

The details of this division are found in `sparse._base.py`, `mat._divide`, with different actions depending whether the `other` is scalar, dense array, or sparse matrix.  Sparse matrix division does not implement `broadcasting`.

As a general rule, matrix multiplication is the most efficient sparse calculation.  In fact actions like row or column sum are implemented with it.  And so are some forms of indexing.  Element-wise calculations are ok if they can be applied to the `M.data` array without regard to row or column indices  (e.g. square, power, scalar multiplication).  `M.multiply` is element-wise, but without the full broadcasting power of dense arrays.  Sparse division is even more limited.

## edit

`sklearn` has some utilities to perform certain kinds of `sparse` actions that it needs, like scaling and normalizing.

```
In [274]: from sklearn.utils import sparsefuncs
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.utils

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs.inplace_row_scale.html#sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs.inplace_row_scale

With the sample `mat`:

```
In [275]: mat
Out[275]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [276]: mat.A
Out[276]: 
array([[1.    , 0.    , 2.    ],
       [0.    , 0.    , 0.1875],
       [4.    , 5.    , 6.    ]])
```

Applying the row scaling:

```
In [277]: sparsefuncs.inplace_row_scale(mat,np.array([10,20,1]))
In [278]: mat
Out[278]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [279]: mat.A
Out[279]: 
array([[10.  ,  0.  , 20.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  3.75],
       [ 4.  ,  5.  ,  6.  ]])
```

The scaling array has to match in length.  In your case you'd need to take the inverse of your `[[1],[2]]`, and pad it with 1 to act on all rows.

Looking at the source I see it uses `sparsefuncs.inplace_csr_row_scale`.  That in turn does:

```
X.data *= np.repeat(scale, np.diff(X.indptr))
```

The details of this action are:

```
In [283]: mat.indptr
Out[283]: array([0, 2, 3, 6], dtype=int32)
In [284]: np.diff(mat.indptr)
Out[284]: array([2, 1, 3], dtype=int32)
In [285]: np.repeat(np.array([10,20,1]), _)
Out[285]: array([10, 10, 20,  1,  1,  1])
In [286]: mat.data
Out[286]: array([100., 200.,  75.,   4.,   5.,   6.])
```

So it converts the `scale` array into an array that matches the `data` in shape.  Then the inplace `*=` array multiplication is easy.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj I’ve read your answer, but I’m still a bit confused. What’s the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a correct way.  Iteratively changing one row at a time may be as good as anything.   I suppose one could also do a lower-level iteration using the `indptr`.

Comment: I found a `sklearn` utility that does this kind of scaling efficiently.

Comment: I found out that I can scale the data before creating the `scr_matrix`, so I was being dumb. But it is good to know how to do that in sparse matrix. Thanks for the help hpaulj!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem lies within the way of accessing the matrix data

```
mat[np.array([0,1])]/=np.array([[1],[2]])
```

The direct access to the rows seems to be the problem. I did not find any reliable data as to why this is the case, but I think that this forces the construction of the rows with all `0` values that the CSR format would normally skip.

A way to mitigate the problem would be to first write the data `np.array([[1],[2]])` as `1/x` to get `[[1],[0.5]]` and then create a diagonal `csr_matrix` from it so that we have

```
mat_x = csr_matrix(([1,0.5,1], [0,1,2], [0,1,2,3]), shape=(3, 3))
```

If we then multiply this matrix from the **left** to affect **rows**, we get the desired output without any warnings

```
mat = mat_x * mat
```

Comment: As with dense arrays, `/=` first computes the division, and then assigns the result back.  It's that's assignment that's triggering the warning.  The division produces a full `np.matrix`, so the assignment changes the sparsity of `mat`.

Comment: `sklearn.utils` has an inplace row (or column) scalar (and other sparse normalizing tools).